# Why PHPexcel insert single quote in date field?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to insert date into the cell using PHPExcel. This is my code:

```
    include('xlsx/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
    include('xlsx/Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation.php');
    include('xlsx/Classes/PHPExcel/Cell.php');
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $start = 3;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('DD.MM.YYYY');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', date('d.m.Y', time()+60*($start + 3)));
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('DD.MM.YYYY');
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);
    $objWriter->save('text.xls');
```

However, PHPexcel choose right format, but it inserts date with single quote

```
'27.02.2016
```

instead

```
27.02.2016
```

I don't know how to insert date without this quote, hope you help me.

Comment: Try reading `02types.php` from `/Examples`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setFormatCode` method sets the format Excel will use to output the date, rather than setting a format for PHPExcel to interpret the date. Excel spreadsheets store dates in a specific timestamp format which can be generated using the `PHPExcel_Shared_Date` class. It has methods for converting between various date formats and Excel's expected format.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1',
    PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(time()+60*($start + 3)));
```

...should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

And one more decision:

```
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', '=NOW()+0.00001*60*'.$start);
```

Comment: This may not give you what you expect: the MS Excel NOW() function is recalculated every time the spreadsheet is opened in MS Excel, so open the file tomorrow and the value shown in cell A1 will be different to the value it shows if you open it today.... the answer you've accepted fixes to date/time at the point where you create the spreadsheet file, because you're storing that Excel timestamp in cell A1, not a volatile formula

Answer (score 0):

This is the same in PHPSpreadsheet in 2021 but the following solution will resolve this:

`$phpSpreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('H'.$start,'=DATE('.date('Y,m,d',strtotime($yourtime)).')');`

You don't obviously have to use `strtotime` but any Unix date stamp or format as long as its `Y,m,d` which Excel dates take as the input format (https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-date-function)

This solution makes use of the inbuilt XLSX date function rather than relying on PhpSpreadsheet.