# How to remove apostrophe before date in PHP spreadsheet

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

I am using php Spreadsheet package to generate and download csv file,

Its putting an apostrophe before number.

```
   public function downloadCsv()
   {
       $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
       $spreadsheet->getProperties()
                   ->setCreator("ABC")
                   ->setTitle("Test");
       $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                   -> setCellValue('A1', '01/02/92')
                   ->setCellValue('A2', '01/02/92')
                   ->setCellValue('A3', '01/04/92');

       $filename = 'hello world';
       $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
       $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter(
            $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
        ->calculateWorksheetDimension()
        );

       header('Content-Type: application/     vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
       header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'.xlsx"');
       header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
       $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
       $writer->save('php://output');
}
```

Output I am getting

```
     '01/02/92
     '01/02/92
     '01/04/92
```

Now how to remove apostrophe before the numbers??
Thanks

Comment: The single apostrophe is so that Excel can recognise it as text. You should specify the type of the column (i.e. date).

Comment: Someone had the same problema (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673245/why-phpexcel-insert-single-quote-in-date-field). Notice that PHPExcel is the old version of PHPSpreadsheet. I had the same problem exporting CSV files. Apparently, the enclosures are malformed. I had to treat single quotation marks aside.

Answer (score 1):

Set cell value `datatype` from `string` to `date`

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter(
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
    ->calculateWorksheetDimension()
    );

/* -----add this line of code----- */
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:A3')
->getNumberFormat()
->setFormatCode(
    \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DATETIME
);

 header('Content-Type: application/     vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'.xlsx"');
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
 $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
 $writer->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need You will need to convert that string to an MS Excel serialized timestamp and then apply a format mask to the cell.

PHPSpreadsheet won't do this for you magically unless you apply a value binder to do it, and the default value binder won't.

The functions for doing a date conversion between unix timestamp or PHP DateTime object and MS Excel timestamp can be found in the `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date` class (`excelToTimestamp()` and `excelToDateTimeObject()` respectively), but you'll need to convert that string to a unix timestamp or DateTime object first, perhaps using something like the [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method. I've no idea whether your format is `d/m/y` or `m/d/y`, but the documentation for that function should show you how to use it.

P.S. Reading the [PHPSpreadsheet documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) can answer a lot of these types of questions for you